# saving get data to a local variable

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, web, get

I was wondering is there a way to save get parameters that the website sends to the server to be saved to a local variable via java script. something like a cookie or the session variable.

EDIT 1:

I am also willing to save it to a server-side cookie, but i still don't know how to do that.

i am using MVC4 in VisualStudio with C# as server-side lang. if there is an easier method to do it server side I'm up for that.

EDIT 2

The comment game me an idea, and i managed to get the solution via the session class server-side. thanks ppl :)

Comment: Probably is, but if you're sending it to the server, using a serverside language to store it in the session or a cookie is usually a lot easier then using javascript.

Comment: Please tag as "asp.net-mvc", not just "mvc". MVC is an architecture, but the technology you're using is ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: sorry, kinda new to the whole thing :) thx for editing my tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `Session.AddItem` method i was able to save all the data i needed. thanks for your help guys.

Comment: Using Session["<insert variable name here>"] is IMHO faster, and easier.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getUrlParams() {
  var params = {};
  window.location.search.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(str,key,value) {
    params[key] = value;
  });

  return params;
}
```